# ESP-01 takes a long time and multiple resets to connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: esp8266, esp01

I have a ESP-01 chip I'm trying to program using the Expressif C SDK. I'm using the ESP chip with a breakout board with a decoupling capacitor. I'm supplying power to it using the 3.3V pin on an Arduino Uno.

I flashed the [Wi-Fi example](https://github.com/espressif/ESP8266_RTOS_SDK/blob/master/examples/wifi/getting_started/station/main/station_example_main.c) from Expressif. For completeness, below is the exact code I'm flashing:

```
/* WiFi station Example

   This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, this
   software is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR
   CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
*/
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "nvs.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"

#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"

/* The examples use WiFi configuration that you can set via project configuration menu

   If you'd rather not, just change the below entries to strings with
   the config you want - ie #define EXAMPLE_WIFI_SSID "mywifissid"
*/
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID      CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_SSID
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS      CONFIG_ESP_WIFI_PASSWORD
#define EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY  CONFIG_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY

/* FreeRTOS event group to signal when we are connected*/
static EventGroupHandle_t s_wifi_event_group;

/* The event group allows multiple bits for each event, but we only care about two events:
 * - we are connected to the AP with an IP
 * - we failed to connect after the maximum amount of retries */
#define WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT BIT0
#define WIFI_FAIL_BIT      BIT1

static const char *TAG = "wifi station";

static int s_retry_num = 0;

static void event_handler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base,
                                int32_t event_id, void* event_data)
{
    if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) {
        esp_wifi_connect();
    } else if (event_base == WIFI_EVENT && event_id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED) {
        if (s_retry_num < EXAMPLE_ESP_MAXIMUM_RETRY) {
            esp_wifi_connect();
            s_retry_num++;
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "retry to connect to the AP");
        } else {
            xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_FAIL_BIT);
        }
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,"connect to the AP fail");
    } else if (event_base == IP_EVENT && event_id == IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP) {
        ip_event_got_ip_t* event = (ip_event_got_ip_t*) event_data;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "got ip:%s",
                 ip4addr_ntoa(&event->ip_info.ip));
        s_retry_num = 0;
        xEventGroupSetBits(s_wifi_event_group, WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT);
    }
}

void wifi_init_sta(void)
{
    s_wifi_event_group = xEventGroupCreate();

    tcpip_adapter_init();

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_loop_create_default());

    wifi_init_config_t cfg = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_init(&cfg));

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &event_handler, NULL));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &event_handler, NULL));

    wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
        .sta = {
            .ssid = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID,
            .password = EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS
        },
    };

    /* Setting a password implies station will connect to all security modes including WEP/WPA.
        * However these modes are deprecated and not advisable to be used. Incase your Access point
        * doesn't support WPA2, these mode can be enabled by commenting below line */

    if (strlen((char *)wifi_config.sta.password)) {
        wifi_config.sta.threshold.authmode = WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK;
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_set_config(ESP_IF_WIFI_STA, &wifi_config) );
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_wifi_start() );

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "wifi_init_sta finished.");

    /* Waiting until either the connection is established (WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) or connection failed for the maximum
     * number of re-tries (WIFI_FAIL_BIT). The bits are set by event_handler() (see above) */
    EventBits_t bits = xEventGroupWaitBits(s_wifi_event_group,
            WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT | WIFI_FAIL_BIT,
            pdFALSE,
            pdFALSE,
            portMAX_DELAY);

    /* xEventGroupWaitBits() returns the bits before the call returned, hence we can test which event actually
     * happened. */
    if (bits & WIFI_CONNECTED_BIT) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "connected to ap SSID:%s password:%s",
                 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
    } else if (bits & WIFI_FAIL_BIT) {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Failed to connect to SSID:%s, password:%s",
                 EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_SSID, EXAMPLE_ESP_WIFI_PASS);
    } else {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "UNEXPECTED EVENT");
    }

    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_unregister(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &event_handler));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_unregister(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &event_handler));
    vEventGroupDelete(s_wifi_event_group);
}

void app_main()
{
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "ESP_WIFI_MODE_STA");
    wifi_init_sta();
}
```

The problem is this setup feels very fragile. When I monitor the serial output using `make monitor`, I see a lot of gibberish being printed. And it's really hard to get it to connect to Wi-Fi. After flashing the program, I have to reset the chip (`RST` pin to `GND`) multiple times to get it connected. When I make even a minor change (e.g., removing the comments), it stops working. I'm wondering if this is normal and what might be causing this. When I issue AT commands directly over serial, it connects to Wi-Fi fine. Following is what I almost always see on the first run after flashing the program:

[image]

EDIT:

I tried erasing the flash before before uploading the program using `make erase_flash flash`. Now, on top of everything else, I'm also getting the following warning message:

```
W (354) phy_init: failed to load RF calibration data (0x1102), falling back to full calibration
```

I used to get this warning before, but it disappeared after a few times of flashing the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue was caused by the power supply. Instead of the 3.3V pin on Arduino Uno, I connected the VCC of the ESP-01 to 5V pin. Now it's working.

Comment: Is not ESP01 limited to 3.6 V ? https://www.microchip.ua/wireless/esp01.pdf §4.5. Note that supply of Arduino UNO can't "supply" an ESP01.

Comment: It is... So this is probably a horrible idea, but it's working... I wouldn't do this when I deploy the project with a proper power supply. This is currently my only option as I don't have a voltage regulator yet.